# Action and Reaction between two people

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

When you hit a person, you apply a force on him. Then according to Newton's third law, there should be an equal and opposite reaction, and that should act on you. So, why don't you fall backward? Is it because opposite force from the other person is used almost entirely to stop your hand? And almost no force is used in moving/pushing you backwards.

Comment: Try it on skates.

Comment: But the person hitted will go more distance than one that hits him

Comment: Who told you that? Seriously. Get two people of approximately the same mass on skate and have them try various pushing off exercises from gentle to violent. Or at least until they get tired of falling down.

Comment: You don't move because you're a big person hitting little people.

Comment: I think the person who hits won't go backwards much, as most of the force from the other guy will be used to stop his hands which was initially in a violent state

Comment: i'm taking mass to be equal

Comment: Don't think. Try. You have, I'm sure, seen a certain amount of people hitting each other either in person or filmed, but those cases generally involve people in contact with the ground. That contact implies other large forces acting on the participants. Worse people *react* to being hit, so their muscles get into the game. SO you need to isolate those effects before you can test Newton's laws.

Comment: i'm just saying that opposite force from the other guy (the one who is hitted) is used almost entirely to stop the person's(who is hitting) hands.

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare this with a situation where two rigid body collide. First moving with some velocity and second at rest. After applying conservation of momentum and energy, you see that the one moving with some speed looses kinetic energy and other gains.

Comment: It's not because the other person will move a way.

Comment: @ALec Teal What is not because other person will move away? Be explicit.

Comment: yes , please clarify